# Python dictionary can't init from 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to loop through a dictionary in python. When I load the dictionary in directly through a Pandas dataframe, I get the error 'can't init from 0' for said dictionary.

Here's what the dictionary looks like:

```
{0:1, 1:3, 2:2}
```

I know the dictionary is being processed correctly from Pandas, because I've printed it prior to the loop and everything looks fine. Here's the code I'm using to convert the df to my dictionary:

```
my_dict = df.to_dict()
```

For some reason, **when I copy/paste the printed output from the conversion above into my dictionary alias prior to the loop, it works correctly**, but when I **feed in my converted dict directly I get the error 'can't init from 0'**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do? So you have a dictionary... but why are you converting it to a Pandas DataFrame, converting said DataFrame back into a dictionary, and looping to it?

Comment: You will increase your change to get a good answer if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).